# Can I insert a function inside of a prompt?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm trying to launch a really basic chat app for myself and a few friends and wanted to include a password check upon loading the site by using a prompt + socket.emit:

```
var username = prompt('password:');
socket.emit('password', password);
```

I wanted to insert a function that checks their input against whatever I define as the answer. Something like this:

```
var codeword = prompt('password:', function checkPrompt(password) {
            if (prompt.password.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (password.value !== answer.value) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
            });
```

But I get `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value);` once I run the app. How can I implement this?

**Sidenote:** I know this is super insecure. I'll implement a real password check once I have a DB set up but until then I just wanted a simple placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt` is a "blocking" method, so there is no need for a callback. Callbacks are needed when you are uncertain when code within the callback will be executed. This is not the case here. You can work with the returned result in a `do...while` loop for example.

Dummy example with static password check:

```js
// We will keep the user in the loop until the password is correct...
do {
   var password = prompt('Password:');
} while (password !== 'abcd');

// At this point we know the password was correct.
alert('Password was correct!');
```

Dummy example with dedicated auth method:

```js
function authenticate(username, password) {
  if (username == 'john' && password == 'abcd') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// We will keep the user in the loop until the password is correct...
do {
   var username = prompt('Username:');
   var password = prompt('Password:');
   var loginSuccessful = authenticate(username, password);
} while (!loginSuccessful);

// At this point we know the password was correct.
alert('Password was correct!');
```

From the security point of view, it only makes sense to have the authentication logic on server-side, so you'll most probably will want to make an AJAX call from within the above `authenticate` function (using the Fetch API for example or `jQuery.post` - if you're using jQuery). Then the method would return `true` or `false` based on the response of the server-side call.

Comment: Ahh ok I didn’t think to use “do” for this. I wanted to make sure the prompt came up right after the username prompt so this should work! Would users be able to find the password for the site through inspect element?

Comment: I have extended my answer to make it a bit clearer on how to work further.

Comment: I really appreciate that! figure I'll just import jquery.js on the index.html, add the AJAX call in my chat.js and that will properly hide it? Cool. Thank you for the help